# Azure data factory data flow task cannot take on prem as source

Tags: azure, dataflow, azure-data-factory

[image]

Hey, 
I am having trouble in creating a Data Flows task which uses an on-prem source. Is this not possible in the Preview version?

I have created a self hosted IR to connect ADF to my laptop, and that is what I want to use. In the pic below I am trying to create a dataset off self hosted IR. It works great in Copy task but for Data Flows it is greyed out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this question, I asked Azure support for help and they replied me with the answer:

**Answer:**

This means on-premise SQL server is not supported as dataset in data flow in current stage.

Screen shot:
[image]

**Update**:

Data flow now only support Azure IR so it doesn’t support on-premise dataset. 
Refer to [Integration runtime types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-integration-runtime#integration-runtime-types).
[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to use visual data transformations in ADF using Mapping Data Flows with on-prem data, then build a pipeline with a Copy Activity first. Use the Self-Hosted Integration Runtime with the Copy Activity to stage your data in Blob Store. Then add a subsequent Execute Data Flow activity to transform that data.

I made video on how to do this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IN-4v0e7UIs

Answer (score 1):

Reproduce your issue on my side ,however nothing about this feature is claimed on the official document. As you can see everywhere about data flow cliams that:

[image]

You could submit any voice here:

[image]

Also found a [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/suggestions/37472797-data-flows-add-support-to-access-on-premise-sql-a) for data flow in ADF for your reference.If you need push the progress of it,you could vote up it. Also,i would suggest you referring to the comments in the link:

> For access to the 80+ ADF connectors, use Copy Activity to stage data
>   for transformation.
>
> Data Flows will access data in your lake (Blob, ADB, ADW, ADLS) for
>   transformation.
>
> Think of Copy Activity as your data heavy-lifting activity and Data
>   Flow as your data transformation engine.